# Connect to Windows azure storage table from Lightswitch 2012

Tags: azure-table-storage, lightswitch-2012

I need to connect to Windows azure storage table from Lightswitch 2012 app. I found [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6a010249-4786-4d91-9aef-eda8ec474a9f) extension, but it is only for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 any adsices ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok it seems nobody knows anything about LS .. so i found how to do it...I downloaded VS2010 and LS2011 then i made project connected to my tables and cut the project and paste it to solution in 2012 updated references and it worked ..

Comment: It's not that nobody knows anything about LS, just not about that particular extension. Glad you got sorted anyway :)

Comment: :-) i Asked 2 different questions on LS and didnt get any answer so it seems like nobody using LS